# TRACEPOINT in visual studio : have you some tricks to share?

Tags: visual-studio

TRACEPOINT are so useful and  I use them often but I still suspect i'm missing some trick-macro?-

Suggestions ?

---

**results**

1. {$TICK,d} to show the current CPU tick count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VS dialog box doesn't mention that you can use `$TICK` for the current CPU tick count and `$FILEPOS` for the current file position.

To get the `$TICK` value to appear in decimal instead of hex, use `{$TICK,d}`

Comment: funky. but the resultof  "cpu -> $tick"  is "cpu -> 0x6047BD3"  any idea to format ?